# Capturar ultimo JSON (respuesta) generado en la pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

les cuento mi problema, estoy con un UserScript y mediante la siguiente función yo detecto la petición (respuesta) de un JSON para llenar una tabla

```
(function(open) {
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
        this.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
            //console.log(this.readyState);
           procesaDatosMatchess(this.response);
        }, false);
        open.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

y hasta ahora me funciona bien, el problema es que necesito usarlo en otra pagina y NO funciona, supongo que NO se estára activando el "readystatechange" y por lo tanto no ejecuta la función, una curiosidad es que en dicha página el "window.location.hash" siempre me está regresando vácio, es como si la página no hubiera cargada o no se.

ahora, hay alguna forma de yo capturar (leer) el ultimo JSON que se genere en la pagina?, con eso me sería suficiente, ya que en la pagina al hacer scroll se hace una petición de un JSON (y se actualiza una tabla, OJO, no necesito leer la tabla, necesito el JSON) y eso es lo que quisiera realizar.

espero me hayan entendido, Gracias

Answer (score 0):

que va, NO soy capaz de obtener el responseText con la respuesta que me dieron, solo logro obtener la url, y con esa url intento realizar una nueva consulta pasando esa url, pero igual NO obtengo nada

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
// url ya tiene la direccion que obtuve con el la respuesta anterior con ajaxCalls 
xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true, user, password); 
xmlHttp.send(null);
alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
```

pero NO obtengo nada, si quito las variables user, password, obtengo un invalid token, es lo mas que logro obtener
no soy experto programando, intento realizar las cosas por ensayo y error, pero de verdad que ya me tiene frustrado esto, no logro obtener un simplo JSON que ya fue generado, de seguro estoy haciendo algo mal, pero no lo veo

Answer (score -1):

Simon. Me imagino que te valdrá la a una pregunta similar de Daniel Vasallo [How to view the last GET HTTP request in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3799278/844212)
Ahí lo que hace es registrar las URLs en un array, pero de la misma forma podrás registrar las respuestas en lugar de las URLs de las llamadas.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:** A sugerencia de padaleiana, añado el fragmento de código al que se hace referencia:

```
    var ajaxCalls = [];
    
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype._originalOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
       ajaxCalls.push(url);
       this._originalOpen(method, url, async, user, password);
    }
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 2:** A petición de @SimonMolina, propongo un código extra más cercano directamente a lo que pide. Ahora se almacenarían en el array ajaxCalls todas las llamadas con 3 propiedades, aunque podrías adaptarlo a lo que necesites. Y en responseText tendrías la respuesta:

```
   var ajaxCalls = [];
    
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype._originalOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
        this.addEventListener("readystatechange", function(event) {  
            if(this.readyState == 4){
            var self = this;
            var response = {
                method: method,
                uri: uri,
                responseText: self.responseText
            };
            ajaxCalls.push(response);
            console.log('Cambio de estado readystate (4)...',response.responseText);  
            } else {
                console.log('Cambio de estado intermedio readystate...',this.readyState);
            }
        }, false);

       this._originalOpen(method, url, async, user, password);
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, creo que por alli es la cuestión, pero creo que NO se como implementarlo, he intentado varias formas y no lo logro.
intente cambiar url por responseText o por response y NO funciona (al final agregue un alert para ver el contenido de ajaxCalls)
alert(ajaxCalls[0]);

pero nada, simpre dice undefined, si lo hago asi alert(ajaxCalls) siempre muestra vacio
la verdad no logro, o me faltará algo en mi userscript un @include a Ajax ??
tambien intente agregando adicionalmente el responseText como un parametro extra en la función pero tampoco

Comment: amigo, puedes ayudarme en como registrar la respuesta (responseText), la verdad lo he intentado todo el día y no doy con la forma, gracias

Comment: Hago una segunda actualización respondiendo a lo que comentas, @SimonMolina

Comment: muchas gracias amigo VFG, lamentablemente voy a tener que desistir, no me funciona, creo un userscript con solo ese codigo, y en la primera pagina efectivamente se activa, pero como que bloquea algo y NO carga por completo la web; en la segunda pagina NO se activa nunca (intente con onload y nada); hasta ahora lo unico que me ha funcionado fue el codigo original que coloque en mi consulta ((function(open) {...) pero solo en la primera pagina, en la segunda NO hay manera que funcione; es una pagina de ajedrez (dchess), y la idea es poder leer información sobre mis partidas, nuevamente gracias